# Can't upload .css file to CloudApp

Tags: css

Is it possible to upload a CSS file to [CloudApp](http://my.cl.ly)? I have already uploaded HTML, PNG, and some font files with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. [Here](http://f.cl.ly/items/333r2a393I341h043m31/test.css) is a CSS file I just uploaded. It gets categorized as text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I previously just tried the same thing many times. I read your answer, tried it again, and it worked! Kinda odd. Cloudapp is awesome though, love the tiny direct links and pretty code. :)